# Excel 2010: I need to offset cell selection ten cells to the right when entering specific text

Tags: vba, excel

In the spreadsheet, I want to make it automatically select column P whenever I type the letters FR and press enter into any cell in column F.

What code will do this?

Comment: Do a `worksheet_change` on column F. Also, I think you mean to select the corresponding cell in column P, not the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following event routine to the worksheet's code module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Text = "FR" Then Target.Offset(, 10).Select
End Sub
```

If you want to select the whole column P not only the cell on the same row,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Text = "FR" Then Columns("P").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: ... or to select all of column P with the ActiveCell in the same row as Target then `Range("P" & Target.Row & ",P:P").Select`.